# Laravel: should i use @include inside loops?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Below i provided two example of displaying product card in a loop. The first one seems to me more convenient but i'm worrying about performance because of this @include inside the loop. As this task is pretty common i would like to choose the best way.

### Case 1. Using @include:

**search.blade.php**

```
<div id='search-results'>   
    @foreach($items as $item)
         @include('items._item')
    @endforeach
</div>
```

**_item.blade.php**

```
<div>
    <div class='item-title'>{{$item->title}}</div>
    <div class='item-description'>{{$item->description}}</div>
</div>
```

---

### Case 2. Without @include:

**search.blade.php**

```
<div id='search-results'>
    @include('items._items_list')
</div>
```

**_items_list.blade.php**

```
@foreach($items as $item)
    <div class='item-title'>{{$item->title}}</div>
    <div class='item-description'>{{$item->description}}</div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Do however you want it to be. It all comes down to your own preference.

Comment: i think blade is good at caching. so no worries about including multiple times.

Comment: There really isn't a lot of difference here, you should opt for the one your feel convenient to use. But I'd personally prefer the second one. Blade caching, eventually generates a normal `php` file out of these templates, so no worries. Use either one.

Comment: @FlexElektroDeimling @Huzaib Shafi are you sure that caching helps in this case? I found this in generated `php`  `<?php foreach($items as $item): ?>
    <?php echo $__env->make('items._item', array_except(get_defined_vars(), array('__data', '__path')))->render(); ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>`

Comment: There is a lot of work for each iteration : `$__env->make('items._item', array_except(get_defined_vars(), array('__data', '__path')))->render();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can potentially create a huge performance issue. When you loop your `@include` as in the first case, the generated raw php file does indeed call the included view as a function. This slows down the page rendering somewhat.

The second case is more performant since it basically is 1 include (with a loop containing a html snippet).

I'm encountering this issue right now. I have a datatable which loops 250 records, but each record contains like 5 helpers. In my case these helpers are quite vital and contain some necessary (simple) logic, but even with simple logic, 1250 subviews will result in a massive performance drop, reducing load time of the page to 5-6s compared to 300-400ms when copying over this helper code.

I was taking an effort to write a Laravel extension that would parse all `@include` and replace it with the actual code, but its not an easy task...

#### Example 1: Looking at how blade parses your `@foreach` loop

Consider this very simple foreach loop. It simply outputs the `name` of an object in an `<h1>` tag for each element:

```
@foreach($paymentMethods as $paymentMethod)
    <h1>{{ $paymentMethod->name }}</h1>
@endforeach
```

You can see that the generated data inside `storage/framework/views/*.php` comes out a bit more complex:

```
<?php $__currentLoopData = $paymentMethods; $__env->addLoop($__currentLoopData); foreach($__currentLoopData as $paymentMethod): $__env->incrementLoopIndices(); $loop = $__env->getLastLoop(); ?>
    <h3>
        <?php echo e($paymentMethod->name); 
    </h3>
<?php endforeach; $__env->popLoop(); $loop = $__env->getLastLoop(); ?>
<?php /**PATH C:\xampp\sites\someproject\resources\views/payment_providers.blade.php ENDPATH**/ ?>
```

Various helpers from the `$__env` object are being called. These will for instance add extra functionality to your `@foreach` loop like the `$loop->first`/`$loop->last` variables (see https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade).

#### Example 2: an `@include` statement

```
@include('myhelper')
```

```
<?php echo $__env->make('myhelper', \Illuminate\Support\Arr::except(get_defined_vars(), ['__data', '__path']))->render(); ?>
```

The `$__env->make()` function resolves to `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Factory.php`, which evaluates your blade helper. This process includes finding the view file itself, parsing it through the blade engine again, dispatching events...

Blade shortcuts will undoubtedly have a performance impact. It only depends on how many you are using and if it's worth the extra few milliseconds for you.

Imho it's a very worthwhile optimization for production environments, if you happen to need to loop big collections and are using many `@include` statements. I would then suggest to resort to a standard `<?php foreach($arr as $item): ?>`/`<?php endforeach ?>` syntax, in combination with some simple php functions that return html if you need re-useable html pieces.

Answer (score 0):

I tested this behavior by using 75 rows that passed to some blade then iterate over this 75 rows twice. 
the first using only blade code inside this blade file and the other was call @include another blade file that has the same code and mark  the time using microtime(true) php function at start and end of each irritation 
The time was increased 3 times in case of using @include.

Answer (score -1):

The first way seems like the most correct way to do this.